# Force browsers to download a file rather than open

Tags: php, download

I'm using typical PHP code to download documents:

```
  header('Content-Type: ' . $mimeTypes[$fileext]); 
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  header('Cache-Control: private');
  header('Pragma: private');

  readfile($filepath);
```

Everything works fine - a download/save-as dialog opens, except for .doc files which attempt to open in docs.google.com but they fail due to lack of permission - that's because I'm serving files from outside a website root.

So how do I bypass docs.google and force **every** browser to offer save-as dialog regardless of the file mime type? `('doc' => 'application/msword')`

I tried the following to no avail:

1. in .htaccess file:

   ```
   <FilesMatch "\.(?i:doc)$">
       ForceType application/octet-stream
       Header set Content-Disposition attachment
   </FilesMatch>
   ```
2. in .htaccess file:

   ```
   AddType application/octet-stream .doc
   ```
3. in PHP script:

   ```
   header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
   ```

Comment: Have you tried using [HTML5](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download)?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your headers:

```
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
```

Comment: Why else would I post it? :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this info! I will use it wisely :-)

Comment: Dzięki Maciej. I edited my question to make use of code formatting. I described three attempts none of which worked.

Comment: This has to work unless you are using funky browser and/or browser plugins. This is however a [hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548573/application-force-download), which does not guarantee success. It all depends on the clinet. There is however no other way to tell the client what to do with the file.

Comment: Try following things:
Check other browser; disable plugins; make sure you are sending the headers correctly (by looking at raw request using Firebug or similar tool); try adding `Content-Length` header.

Answer (score 0):

The following php worked for me

```
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file."");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Type: binary/octet-stream"); 
readfile ($link);
```

P.S. - I used the File extension in the `$file` variable only, so no need to mention *mime type*...

Hope this helps :)