# Play and download audio file on the same page in Drupal

Tags: audio, drupal, drupal-7, download

First of all i work with Drupal 7.

I have a custom content type which allows me to upload an audio file.
I found a way to play the audio file when the user access a page of this content type.

Now i want to let the user download the audio file, but not remove the play capabilities. I want to add a download button on the same page (details page of the content type).

Can someone explain me how to do it ? I've got nowhere on this matter.

Comment: You can download any attached files by default. Check the display settings of your file field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, depending on your drupal expertise. If you are using [node templates](https://drupal.org/node/1089656), then you can print the same variable twice, once inside the music player plug in, and once with a download button. Something like this:

```
...... prints other fields .....

<my-audio-player src="<?php print $node->field_my_audio_field;?>"/>

<a href="<?php print $node->field_my_audio_field;?>">Click to download</a>

...... prints other fields .....
```

To force the download instead of opening, check this: [Force browsers to download a file rather than open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124064/force-browsers-to-download-a-file-rather-than-open)

To achieve this without writing any code or templates, you can do what Fleix Eve have suggested above. Set the display settings as direct download. Then create a block [view](https://drupal.org/project/views) which shows your audio file field, take the argument from URL. Then set tat block to display on node-view.